# Apache Kafka Connector Monitoring and Alerting using Datadog required Configuration

Tags: javascript, java, javabeans, apache-kafka-connect, datadog

[image]We needed help in implementing the watchdog for Snowflake Kafka connector:

However, was able to go ahead and implement as per the standards of datadog
But however kafka connector and its related statistics are not visible in this.

Below link has helped for the Snowflake based database and was able to configure successfully, but nothing related to Kafka Connector is present in this.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/snowflake/#snowflake-custom-queries

Answer (score 1):

You should configure Datadog Agent to do JMX fetching. Only then will you be able to export Connect worker and Connector Mbean metrics.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/?tabs=host

Comment: You can also do an HTTP check of the general Connect endpoints https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/http_check/

Comment: Well configured and integrated Kafka with Datadog, but not able to see all the metrics, attached the screen shot in the main query of the dashboard

Comment: I suggest contacting Datadog support about that. The image you've shown is for the brokers, and not related to a specific connector, as your question was about

Comment: Everything cannot be with the product team, yes many are open source tools nowadays in market.

Comment: Huh? You said you are having an issue with what is shown by Datadog. So _ask **them**_ about it.